# GEE: Clip() doesn't work properly

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a question about the code below. Although I've defined `geometry` as a triangle, when I download the file, the image has a square shape. I running that code using node js. Can you help me, please?

```
  ee.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey(config.gee, () => {

    ee.initialize();

    var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-58.22065005792236, -38.39475941140011],[-58.21198115838623, -38.391698569574615],[-58.222109179626464, -38.38813303001853]]])

    var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(geometry).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5));

    var cloudMasked = collection.map(image => {
      var cloud = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
      var cirrus = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
      var qa = image.select('QA60');
      var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrus).eq(0));
      return image.updateMask(mask);
    });

    var ndvi = cloudMasked.map(image => {
      return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'));
    });

    var reducer = ee.Reducer.percentile([90]);
    var ndvi90 = ndvi.select(['NDVI']).reduce(reducer).clip(geometry);
    var url = ndvi90.getDownloadURL({'region':geometry,'scale': 10})

    console.log(url);     
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the export in GEE it will use the bounding box of the geometry

[image]

This is because images have to be rectangular (when stored in a standard file format).

Comment: So, I've no way to clip a triangle shape using node?

Comment: The image has to be rectangular but if you want to set pixels outside of the geometry to zero (or some other value) then I think you can use unmask().. 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279907/gee-how-to-transform-masked-values-nodata-to-9999/279924#279924